# ¿Por qué se genera el error Dropping invalid columns in DataFrameGroupBy.mean is deprecated?

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

este es mi codigo que estoy probando

```
import pandas as pd 
import openpyxl

df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Dacb/Desktop/Examen/PRODUCTOS POVINCIAS.xlsx',header=None,names=['CONTRATO','AVISO','ID_PROD','NOMBRE_PRODUCTO','ABREVIATURA','TIPO_PRODUCTO','COSTO'])

#print(list(df))

pv = pd.pivot_table(df,values="COSTO",index=["ABREVIATURA"],columns=["TIPO_PRODUCTO"])
```

error que me aparece:

> FutureWarning: Dropping invalid columns in DataFrameGroupBy.mean is deprecated. In a future version, a TypeError will be raised. Before calling .mean, select only columns which should be valid for the function.
> pv = pd.pivot_table(df,values="COSTO",index=["ABREVIATURA"],columns=["TIPO_PRODUCTO"])

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Esa es una advertencia, no un error, te dice que la función va a ser obsoleta en el futuro

Comment: Siguiendo lo que te dicen en el otro comentario, ¿por qué afirmas que es un error? El código deja de hacer lo que debe hacer?